# Abrir planilha Excel e copiar os Dados em VBS

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, vbs, vbscript

Olá, tenho uma planilha simples (3 cols e 2 rows) e estou tentando criar um script para abri-la, copiar seus dados e inserir em outra.

```
Path = "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\excell\planilha1.xlsx"
Set objexl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
objexl.Visible = True
Set objwkb = objexl.Workbooks.Open(Path)
Set objsht = objwkb.Sheets(1)
objsht.Range("A2").Select
objsht.Range(Selection.End(xlToRight), Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

quando executo, a planilha abre e o seguinte erro é retornado: `Objeto necessário: 'Selection'`, e o erro ocorre na linha 7. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
Path = "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\excell\planilha1.xlsx"
Set objexl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
objexl.Visible = True
Set objwkb = objexl.Workbooks.Open(Path)
Set objsht = objwkb.Sheets(1)
set vRange = objsht.Range("A2")
objsht.Range(vRange.End(xlToRight), vRange.End(xlDown)).Copy
```

Normalmente este erro se dá por que o Excel não consegue identificar adequadamente quam é o seu "selection" por mais que voce tenha definido acima. Eu não sei lhe detalhar este problema, mas a solução é evitar usar comandos de interação do Excel como o "SELECTION" e usar o range diretamente, como mencionei no codigo acima.

Comment: muito obrigado, deu certo, o mais engraçado é que eu juro que tinha tentado fazer essa solução que você me passou kkk